# Is $10^n+n^{10}$ prime for some integer $n \ge 2$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, prime-numbers

> Is $$f(n):=10^n+n^{10}$$ a prime number for some integer $n\ge 2$ ?

Two necessary conditions :

- $\gcd(n,10)=1$
- Since $n$ must be odd , we must also have $11\mid n$ , otherwise $11\mid f(n)$

In particular , $n$ must be of the form $22k+11$

I could not find any restrictions concerning algebraic or aurifeuillan factors. The case $5\mid n$ would us give the sum of the fifth powers , but because of the factor $5$ we cannot have a prime in this case anyway.

So, $n$ must be of the form $22n+11$ and cannot be divisible by $5$. According to my search there is no prime $f(n)$ upto $n=50\ 000$.

The $10^6$-candidates ($n$ for which $f(n)$ has no prime factor below $10^6$) between $50\ 000$ and $100\ 000$ are :

```
50567 50611 51051 51073 51249 51447 51491 51513 51667 51689 51711 51909 51931 52151 52437 52921 53207 53537 53669 53889
53999 54307 54351 54659 54681 54989 55187 55561 55693 55737 55869 56111 56199 56551 56881 57079 57211 57321 57343 57431
57519 57827 58443 58641 58729 59103 59367 59631 59741 59829 60093 60247 60291 60357 60533 60599 60731 60929 61061 61171
61479 61677 62161 62403 62601 62843 62909 63239 63503 63723 63877 64273 64339 64471 64933 65197 65989 66099 66737 66759
67111 67177 67199 67617 67639 67683 67859 67881 67969 68101 68123 68321 68607 68629 68871 69311 69509 69707 69773 69883
70191 70367 70389 70521 70631 70939 71181 71643 71687 71841 72017 72149 72237 72259 72611 72743 72831 73073 73403 73887
73931 74129 74173 74349 74393 74437 74503 74591 74789 74811 75031 75251 75273 75339 75361 75449 75603 75713 75801 76373
76461 76527 76901 76923 77077 77121 77297 77319 77363 77561 77759 77781 78243 78551 78683 78727 79013 79057 79233 79387
79607 79651 79871 79893 79937 80003 80091 80333 80641 80883 81367 81521 81829 81851 81983 82071 82159 82841 82907 82929
82951 83237 83303 83391 83677 83787 83853 83919 84469 84667 84843 84931 85019 85217 85393 85481 85503 85613 85657 85767
85877 86009 86097 86119 86339 86427 86559 86647 86823 86867 86889 87043 87241 87373 87439 87549 87747 88209 88363 88407
88451 88539 89243 89551 90101 90519 90981 91047 91223 91883 91993 92807 92917 93093 93819 94083 94281 94457 94919 94941
95227 95337 95843 95887 95931 96019 96239 96569 96679 96723 96811 97229 97493 97603 97779 98131 98483 98527 98659 99297
99473 99737 99759 99803 99869
```

Maybe, this has already been checked. Does anyone know a reference ?

Comment: I'd check with what you know, what is the expected number of primes that you find in the neighbourhood of 10^n + n^10? If n must be in the form 22k + 11, then I'd think that the expected number of primes is roughly the harmonic series divided by a rather large number. In which case the expected number might become 1 when n is very, very large. Beyond reasonable possibility of finding a solution.

Comment: Based on the $10^6$-candidates upto $10^6$ , the expected number of primes with $n$ in the range $[60\ 000,1\ 000\ 000]$ is about $0.154$ , if we replace $1\ 000\ 000$ by $100\ 000$ , the expected number of primes is only about $0.029$. In fact we need some luck to find such a prime.

Comment: The probability for a $10^6$-candidate $n$ giving a prime is about $\frac{10.687}{n}$

Comment: My current search limit is $n=74\ 000$ , doublechecks are very welcome !

Comment: I have searched up to $n=150\ 000$ without finding any primes.

Comment: In general, these are called Leyland primes - see OEIS A094133 and the references cited therein. From [this link](http://chesswanks.com/num/a094133.txt) I don't think there has been a prime of the above form ever found.

Comment: Slight refinement: if $n\equiv5\bmod42$ then $7|10^n+n^{10}$.